# react-native TextInput, how to mask the phone number to look like NN NNN NN NN

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

im using react native TextInput for the phone number, the client want the phone number to look like NN NNN NN NN, found a solution to do spaces for each 3 numbers but that was not enough.

```
const handleCardNumber = (text) => {
    let formattedText = text.split(' ').join('');
    if (formattedText.length > 0) {
      formattedText = formattedText.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join(' ');
    }
    //this.setState({ cardNumber: text });
    console.log(formattedText)
    return formattedText;
  }
```

this is the code i tried

Comment: Does this answers the question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233596/insert-spaces-into-string-using-string-format

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-input-mask

Comment: @PhantomSpooks thank you for the answer but im trying to use the react-native textinput since these packages are laggy.

Comment: I think, this is something you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877844/20860690